# listar ip que estan haciendo consultas hacia la base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema a nivel de SQL y necesito saber como capturar la ip desde donde se estan haciendo las consultas sql y que usuarios.

Active una traza de seguridad pero no logro ver el detalle..

tambien use la sentencia:

declare @IP_ADDRESS varchar (255):
select @ip_address client_net_address
from sys.dm_exec_connections
where session_id@@spid:

Alguien que pueda ayudarme

Comment: Seria bueno saber el lenguaje. En base a eso puedes hacer un log con lo que haga el usuario. En su momento yo hice uno, y con mas de 50 tiendas me funcionó de maravilla, se podía ver qué hacia quien, y a que hora, siempre...

Comment: Estamos en SQLServer la consulta la haria desde alli es para hacer varios descartes y ver que usuario esta aciendo que a nivel de las bases de datos, y tambien su ip importnatisimo eso ultimo. Tienes alguna consulta que pueda servirme...

Comment: ¿Quieres algo que esté capturando de forma permanente cada consulta que se hace o algo para ver lo que está pasando en cierto instante? La solución es muy distinta.

Comment: Ups, no fui lo suficientemente claro, **Lenguaje de Programación**. Yo lo que hacía era a nivel de progra (PHP). Capturaba todo lo que hacían los usuarios.

Comment: debe existir una consulta que me permita ver que y quien esta haciendo algo sobre el sql, tambien si fecha, hora y direccion ip que me permita conocer quien esta haciendo un update, se que en auditorias puedo colocarlo pero no me aparecen las opciones, por ejemplo update

Comment: Por ejemplo en las sqlaudit en las opciones a nivel de insert, update y delete no me aparecen las opciones para hacerlo